# Kotlin: Is it no longer possible to iterate a map with destructured Entry? Bug?

Tags: dictionary, for-loop, iteration, kotlin

It seems like with the latest Kotlin update you can no longer iterate through maps with destructured `Entry`. For example:

```
val map = HashMap<Int, String>()

for ((i, s) in map) { // compiler error here
    ... // code
}
```

[image]

The compiler error is `For-loop range must have an iterator() method`

This feature previously worked as expected, iterating through each entry in the map. I have also tried to use `map.entries` and `map.entrySet()` (deprecated) and with these:

[image]

What is the idiomatic way to iterate through a map now? Is this a bug?

Comment: Your question is missing information needed to help answer your question.  For example, what version of Kotlin were you using that worked, versus which did not work?  Also, if you think this is a bug, then you should report it to the Kotlin issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I think this question might be invalid now, it was caused by using a very old plugin of Kotlin so the question is based on not knowing you were on an old version of Kotlin.  Can the author please add a note to the top of the question that this was NOT a problem with current Kotlin and the question be closed?   The question is really "if I use a very old version of Kotlin on accident, why do current features not work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in IDE and Gradle plugins. I tried the following:

- Created a clean Gradle project with Kotlin 4584 and pasted your code. The bug was there, the same to your occurence.
- Changed Kotlin version to the previous one, 4583, and reimported the project. The code compiled well.
- Changed Kotlin version back to 4584, and the bug didn't show itself, the code compiled successfully.

No following changes could let me reproduce the bug in this project, but I could in a new one.

Comment: That's interesting! I got it fixed by downloading the plugin off JetBrain's plugin repository (http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=idea) and then installing the plugin from disk.

Comment: @Jire, that looks even stranger as I could not reproduce the same after I created two more projects where I could...

Comment: @Jire, I could reproduce it again: I just needed to accept IDE's suggestion on Gradle file. However, the bug disappears on any project re-import, so it seems a minor one.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly IntelliJ offered me to "update" to Kotlin plugin 2428 which caused this.

Downloading off JetBrain's plugin repository (Kotlin plugin here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=idea) and choosing `Install from disk...` in IntelliJ fixed the problem.